# Issue with Application Modeller - Unable to Select "Windows Application" Option

Tags: blueprism

I am writing to seek assistance with an issue I am experiencing in Blue Prism regarding the Application Modeller functionality.

I am attempting to set up an application model using the Application Modeller in Blue Prism. However, I am encountering a problem where I am unable to select the "Windows Application" option as instructed in the documentation. This option does not appear in the list of choices provided.

Steps Taken:

I have verified that I am using a compatible version of Blue Prism that should support the "Windows Application" option.
I have checked my Blue Prism license and ensured that my user account has the necessary permissions to access the Application Modeller.
I have restarted Blue Prism and attempted to reinstall it to see if the issue persists, but it remains unresolved.
Additional Details:

Blue Prism Version: v7.3.0
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro
I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide in resolving this issue. Please let me know if you require any further information from my end.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.